# is defining a function first more efficient or is it better to def when is about be used?(see example)

Tags: python, optimization, python-3.x, performance

on (1) I define a function on the first line.
on (2) I define the same function on line 5.

which one is faster? is defining a function "closer" to when I need it impractical for the complexity of larger programs(but does it make it faster), or defining a function "far" from where I need it makes a larger program slower when running(but also more practical).

I am using python. of course the difference here is probably in nano seconds but this is just an example.

1-

```
def t(n1,n2):
    v=n1-n2
    return abs(v)
a = int(input('how old are you? \n'))
b = int(input('how old is your best friend? \n'))

c=t(a,b)

if a==b:
    print ('you are both the same age')

else:
    print('you are not the same age\nthe difference of years is %s year(s)' % c)

input()
```

2-

```
a = int(input('how old are you? \n'))
b = int(input('how old is your best friend? \n'))

def t(n1,n2):
    v=n1-n2
    return abs(v)

c=t(a,b)

if a==b:
    print ('you are both the same age')

else:
    print('you are not the same age\nthe difference of years is %s year(s)' % c)

input()
```

Comment: You *just asked this*.

Comment: I tried to do it simpler because I had -'s and 0 answers and thought nobody would answer it. but you did after I made this one. should I delete one?

Answer (score 2):

Both are the same. As long as you don't call a function (or use a variable etc.) before defining it, it doesn't matter where you put it. All your code is optimized by the Python interpreter anyway, and it couldn't care less how "far" away from the function call the function is defined.

Comment: I thought that it would be faster by defining function as soon as you need it, so this two programs run at the same speed? is there a way I can test the speed?. What about in a different language? and if the program is very large about 8 thousand lines an I define the function at line 1 and use it at line 7900, and the other is 8 thousand lines and I define it at 7899 and use it at 7900? is there a small difference of nanoseconds or not?

Comment: @marsulld When you define a function, it's "saved for later". No matter how far away the function call, the computer is still looking at the same place for the function. As a result, it makes no difference, in any language, how far away the function call is (even if the program is 8000 lines, or 10000 lines, or more). As for testing the difference, it's not practical. Even if there were a difference of nanoseconds, there are so many other things going on on your computer that it'd be impossible to eliminate enough noise to get an accurate reading.

Answer (score 0):

The function gets parsed before you call it. So it doesn't matter where you have defined it.